# Как использовать класс JavaScript вместе с классом Реакт?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

У меня есть написанный на JS класс Бургер-меню. В нём есть разные настройки. Я хочу использовать его в своём Реакт приложении. Я хочу чтобы по нажатию на кнопку меню (оно является отдельным компонентом) уезжало за экран и при повторном нажатии возвращалось обратно. Я этот функционал в классе JS написал.
Теперь как мне использовать этот JS-код в классе Реакта?
Я не хочу вставлять большое количество кода в какие-нибудь методы класса Реакта.
Возможно ли как-то импортировать мой класс Бургер-меню в класс Реакта и использовать их совместно?

Вот мой написанный класс Бургер-меню:
https://github.com/konstantinstepanyan/Menu-Toggler

Как мне засунуть его в компонент Реакта, чтобы код класса Реакта остался читабельным и красивым?

Благодарю за внимание.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import nameClass from "./link/"
```

Так можно подключить к проекту скрипт. Далее по стандарту

```
const name = new nameClass()
```